# How can I Use th:selected attribute in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

```
   <select name="fGroup-selector">
                <option th:each="fGroup : ${fGroupsList}"
                        th:value="${fGroup.id}"
                        th:selected="${fGroup.is_default}"
                        th:text="${fGroup.name}">fGroup
                </option>
            </select>
It is not working....
```

This is thymeleaf dropdown list code in which th:selected attribute is not working Please any help me

Comment: Do you really have getters/setters on you fGroup object named `boolean isIs_default()` or `getIs_default`?  If your property is called default, and you have a getter isDefault(), it should look like this: `th:selected="${fGroup.default}"`.

Comment: Yes sir I have getter and setter But it still not work